# featherjs random error: undefined (help finding where console log is coming from)

Tags: feathersjs

I have a random `error: undefined` that keeps getting popped up in my featherjs console and I don't know where it is coming from.

Does anyone know how I can figure out where the `console.log` pops up from?

Answer (score 0):

`console` is the default error logger for the [Feathers Express error handler middleware](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/express.html#expresserrorhandler). You can disable error logging by setting the `logger` option to `false` but you probably want to find out why the Express error handler got triggered without an actual error.

Comment: Yea I don't want it to disappear, I want to figure out where it's coming from. Is there a simple method to figure out what page is generating this undefined error?

Comment: You could customize the `json` error handler as shown in https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/express.html#appuseexpresserrorhandleroptions and in that middleware `console.log(req.url)`.

Comment: if/when you had time,, anyway you could show me an an example of where I would put this? I only see a way to do custom HTML error response in that link. Not sure where I would put that `console.log`

Comment: It's the same thing but with a `json` key instead of `html` (and `res.json(error)` instead of rendering it). For debugging purposes you can also ditch the error handler completely and write your own Express Error handling middleware: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html